# Testing a Spring Boot command line application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'd like to test my Spring Boot command line application. I would like to mock certain beans (which I was able to do by annotating `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)` at the top of my test class. In `TestConfig.class`, I override the beans that I would like to mock. I'd like `Spring Boot` to find the rest of the components. This seems to work.

The problem is that when I run the test, the entire application starts up as normal (ie. the `run()` method is called).

```
@Component
public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    //fields

    @Autowired
    public MyRunner(Bean1 bean1, Bean2 bean2) {
        // constructor code
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // run method implementation
    }
```

I've tried to override the `MyRunner` `@Bean` and put it in `TestConfig.class`, but that doesn't seem to work. I understand that I'm loading the regular application context, but that's what I'd like to do (I think?) since I would like to re-use all (or most) of the `@Component` I created in my Application, and only mock a tiny subset.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: So to get this straight - You want to run from the command line with what's effectively your test context that will mock certain beans? Can you add the Application class (ie the class with the main method you are calling) to the question?

Comment: @stringy05 Edited the question with it. Basically I just want to write a test class where I can have all my components injected (except a few which I mock). The problem is when I run the test method, `MyRunner` gets injected and runs like on application startup, and for whatever reason mocking that class doesn't override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I thought. Add the MockBean in

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

    @MockBean
    private MyRunner myRunner;

}
```

*We can use the @MockBean to add mock objects to the Spring application context. The mock will replace any existing bean of the same type in the application context.*

So `MyRunner.run()` is never called but I can still use all the other beans in my application.

Answer (score 1):

`CommandLineRunners` are ordinary beans with one exception:

After the application context is loaded, spring boot finds among all its beans the beans that implement this interface and calls their `run` method automatically.

Now, I would like you to ask to do the following:

1. Remove `ContextConfiguration` from the test and place a breakpoint in constructor of `MyRunner`. The test should look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // if you're on junit 4, adjust for junit 5 if you need
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class MyTest {
   @Autowired
   private MyRunner myRunner;
   @Test
   public void testMe() {
     System.out.println("hello");
   }
}
```

2. Run the test and make sure that myRunner is loaded and its `run` method is called
3. Now mock this class with MockBean annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // if you're on junit 4, adjust for junit 5 if you need
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class MyTest {

   @MockBean
   private MyRunner myRunner;
   @Test
   public void testMe() {
     System.out.println("hello");
   }
}
```

4. Run the test. Make sure that `run` method is not running. Your Application Context now should contain a mock implementation of your component.
5. If the above works, then the problem is with `TestConfig` and `ContextConfiguration` annotation. In general when you run without `ContextConfiguration` you give spring boot test engine a freedom to mimic the application context started as if its a real application (with autoconfigurations, property resolution, recursive bean scanning and so forth).
   However if you put ContextConfiguration, spring boot test doesn't work like this - instead it only loads the beans that you've specified in that configuration. No Autoconfigurations, no recursive bean scanning happens for example.

**Update**

Based on OP's comment:

It looks like the `MyRunner` gets loaded when you put @ContextConfiguration because of component scanning. Since you have an annotation `@Component` placed on `MyRunner` class it can be discovered by Spring boot engine.

In fact there is a "dangerous" mix of two types of beans definitions here:
1. The beans defined with `@Bean` in `@Configuration` annotation 
2. The beans found during component scanning.

Here is the question for you: If you don't want to mimic the application startup process and instead prefer to load only specific beans, why do you use `@SpringBootTest` at all? Maybe you can achieve the goal with:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(YourConfig.class)
public class MyTest {
  ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is when I remove `@ContextConfiguration`, it picks up all of my application beans. The `TestConfig.class` was for my bean overrides. If I leave `@ContextConfiguration`, the application beans are actually all loaded correctly (including the ones I want to mock), but the `CommandLineRunner` bean is also loaded, and then runs the full app.

Comment: Noted, I've updated the answer in this case, please try my suggestion and update.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I ended up finding out a pretty clean solution (see my own answer)

Comment: Cool, glad you've find the solution. You can also use @MockBean directly in the test, btw. :)

Comment: Thank you! I believe that last example of yours is the best way to do it. It's really hard to find that by googling because there are so many iterations on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to have 2 classes with the main method, one which sets up the "normal" context, and another that sets up the "mock" context:

Normal App Context, uses the usual `Application`

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.demo.api")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo("I am not mocked");
    }

    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar("this is never mocked");
    }
}
```

Add another `Application` class that overrides the normal context with the mocked one

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {MockApplication.class, Application.class})
@Component
public class MockApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(MockApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo("I am mocked");
    }
}
```

When you run `Application.main` Foo will be "I am not mocked", when you run `MockApplication.main()` it will be "I am mocked"

Comment: This gives:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found multiple @SpringBootConfiguration annotated classes`